# How to remove end of substring using regex?

Tags: python, regex

I combined the `Occur_Date` and `Occur_Time` columns (both consisting of strings) into a single string column `Occur_Date_Time`. I am trying to remove the seconds from the time in the new column using the regular expression `r':[0-9]{2}$'`, indicating to remove only the substring starting with a colon followed by two digits ending the string. These have been removed using the strip function, but also more was removed than intended (for example the month in the row at index position 2). I have attached my code for review. Can somebody provide me with some direction in this matter?

[image: Referenced Code]

Answer (score 0):

Doing a positive lookbehind for a number will help:

```
f'(?<=\d):\d{2}$'
```

```
Positive Lookbehind (?<=\d)
Assert that the Regex below matches
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
: matches the character : literally (case sensitive)
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
{2} matches the previous token exactly 2 times
$ asserts position at the end of a line
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I tried this and obtained the same result as before. Not sure why this isn't working; at first I thought it might be an issue with the regex module, but other regex operations I employ work fine.